# acronym package: don't write acronym if single occurence

Tags: acronyms

I use the acronym package for managing acronyms. There is one option I am missing (couldn't find it in the manual): that is, suppressing the abbreviated form if the acronym occurs only once throughout the text.

(The reasoning being that there is no need to use an acronym in the text if the word doesn't reappear elsewhere in the text, however, as an author/editor you don't always know this upfront.)

Is there an easy way to work around this, and make the acronym package do this, without modifying the package itself?

Comment: I can not help you with your actually question. -but the `glossaries` package is more advanced and with many benefits over `accronym`.

Comment: I do agree with your reasoning. I would definitely define the acronym, even if it is not used elsewhere in the text. It will enlighten the reader, and make it possible for the reader to understand the acronym from elsewhere within the same topic.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind switching packages you could used [the package `acro`](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/)(*). It provides the package option `single` which exactly does what you want: don't use an acronym at all if it is used only once throughout the document. However, all in all it is very similar to the `acronym` package.

The following example needs to be run at least twice:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{single}

\DeclareAcronym{nato}{
  short = NATO ,
  long  = North Atlantic Treaty Organization
}
\DeclareAcronym{un}{
  short = UN ,
  long  = United Nations
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
  short = EU ,
  long  = European Union
}
\DeclareAcronym{icc}{
  short = ICC ,
  long  = International Criminal Court
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

Only once: \ac{eu}

Twice: \ac{nato}; again: \ac{nato}

Twice: \ac{icc}; again: \ac{icc}

Once: \ac{un}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(*) *Disclaimer: I am the author*

Comment: Interesting. Is there any specific reason why decided to use different definition macros? E.g. in the example you use `\DeclareAcronym`, whereas the `acronym` package uses `\acrodef`. Seems to me it would be easier for people to switch if you adhere to the 'standard' of the `acronym` package.

Comment: I do not know how to decide what the “standard” way is: `acronym` also allows you to define acronyms with `\acro` inside the `acronym` environment or to use `\newacro`. On the other hand `glossaries` uses `\DefineAcronym`... That is a problem which can be solved by a simple 'search and replace'. What will be more troubling when switching “mid-document” is that the syntax of these commands are different.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I wasn't aware of `glossaries` ...