# Write glossary entries without abbreviation if they only appear once

Tags: glossaries

I find the glossaries package very useful for defining acronyms and then have LaTeX worry about when to write out the full name and acronym (the first time it appears), and subsequently only the acronym. I would, however, like one additional feature: the option to print only the full name (without the acronym) if the term appears only once. I would like this to be done automatically, since I usually do not know which terms I will only mention once beforehand.

As an example, the code snippet

```
\Gls{SEM} is an analysis technique, and so is \gls{xps}. \Gls\{XPS} ...
```

Should render the following text:

Scanning electron microscopy is an analysis technique, and so is X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS). XPS ...

assuming that the glossary entries were defined earlier in the document. The imporant point is that `\Gls{SEM}` does not render any (SEM) after the full definition, since it is only used once.

Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, very much so. I missed that question. The patch in the selected answer from the other question worked for me. I hope to see that functionality built into glossaries in the future (with the possibility to choose whether to use it or not).

Comment: I'd like to see that functionality in `glossaries`, too. Maybe we can convince @NicolaTalbot ...

Comment: I think that it would be best implemented such that the author of a document adds some flag to the preamble if (s)he wants to use the new feature, to preserve backwards compatibility.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: For what it's worth: the `acro` package [provides this functionality with its `single` option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61832/5049).